# jQuery store onclick attribute and re-add it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of calendars on a page. These are made up of HTML tables and each day is a td. Each td has an onClick attribute which I cannot remove or modify in the HTML. I am removing all onClick attributes from the days apart from Friday and Saturday using the following jQuery:

```
var kalvoid = jQuery(".kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(1),.kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(2),.kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(3),.kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(4),.kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(7)");
jQuery(kalvoid).removeAttr("onClick");
```

The problem I have is that I also want to remove the onClick attribute from friday as well and then re-add it if a user clicks on a Saturday. I have been playing around with the following code:

```
var kalfri = jQuery(".kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(5)");
var kalsat = jQuery(".kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(6)");
jQuery(kalfri).removeAttr("onClick");

jQuery(kalsat).click(function() {
  (function(kalfri){
    var kalfriID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    jquery(this).attr("onClick", kalfriID);
  });
});
```

This obviously isn't working (even I can see that the code is wrong), the problem is that I don't know the correct jQuery to do this. I have been playing around with this for some time with no luck. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could just store it in `data()`

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var kalfri = $(".kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(5)");
    var kalsat = $(".kc_mainTable tr td:nth-child(6)");

    kalfri.data('onclick', kalfri.attr('onclick')).removeAttr("onClick");

    kalsat.click(function() {
        var kalfriID = kalfri.data('onclick');
        kalfri.attr("onclick", kalfriID);
    });

});
```

And you don't have to use `jQuery` everywhere

Comment: Thanks for the 'jQuery' tip. I have added your code and unfortunately it doesn't work. The 'onClick' is not being re-added to the Fridays when I click on a Saturday.

Comment: @DesignSubway -It's a little hard to know what elements do what in your code, but it does seem to work when targeting the right elements -> http://jsfiddle.net/rG76L/2/

Comment: You don't need $() in $(kalfri) nor in $(kalsat) either

Comment: @MauricePerry - Nope, you don't!